# add parameters in ssrs url in report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Hello I have ssrs report and I want to pass parameters within URL is it possible?

report link: http://serverName/reports/reportname

it is possible when I access link like below
http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx%2fReportName&rs:Command=Render&ParamerterName = abc
but I want to achieve for link  http://serverName/reports/reportname

can someone please help

Comment: You can't pass parameters this way. Why can't you use the standard method via the web service URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant I use. This passes concatenated parameters/one parameter from a cell in Excel to the SSRS report (each parameter separated by "-") and opens the report in another Excel workbook. The SSRS report is coded to split the parameter into its constituent parts.

```
http://myserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyreports%2fmyfolders%2fmyreport&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=EXCEL&rc:target=_blank&myparam=xxxxx
```

Comment: This works for me too. but I want to pass parameters to http://serverName/reports/reportname